# limit the axes for plotting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, text, scatter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [is it possible to select a particular region in a scatterplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487407/is-it-possible-to-select-a-particular-region-in-a-scatterplot)

is it possible to reduce the datapoints from the input text file, so that those dont come in my calculation. I am using following to read the data

```
fid = fopen('cr.txt');
A =  textscan(fid, '%f %f %f %f %f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*f %*s %*s %*s') ;
%read the file
a = A{1};
e = A{2};
c = A{3};
x = A{4};
y = A{5};
```

here x,y are the distances and if I apply xlim and ylim, I want to limit the corresponding a,e,c from the file also. the file has around million data points.

And I will be further plotting the x,y and z(which is calculated from a,e,c) as a scatter and colorbar
the plotting code I am using for the entire data points is

```
lg=log10(g2);
scatter(x(1:end-1), y(1:end-1),5, lg);
colorbar('eastoutside');
caxis([14 max(lg)]);
xlabel(' X-axis (microns)');
ylabel('Y-axis (microns)');
```

the lg is determined from the a,e,c shown earlier. so all I want to do is do a plot between a selected portion of x,y and the corresponding lg.

please help!!

Comment: If I understand correctly, `xlim` and `ylim` will do exactly what you want. So I must not understand the question! Have you tried using `xlim` and `ylim` and they failed? Note that you don't have to work with the entire million-point data set, just create a smaller data set for testing your plotting code.

Comment: @DanBecker Yup xlim and ylim can limit them, but what about the corresponding z? how can I limit the z to the selected x and y points.

Comment: Can you post your plotting code, and explain the exact problem you are having with it? Include a (very small) set of data so that we can all reproduce the problem.

Comment: @DanBecker can u please guide me with this

Comment: Can you please also include example values for the vectors `x`, `y` and `lg` so that we can reproduce the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can specify the limits directly on the `axes` using `set` or by calling the `xlim`, `ylim`, and `zlim` [functions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html)

```
plot(rand(1,100));
set(gca,'XLim', [10 20] ); % set the xlims to 10,20
```

or

```
plot(rand(1,100));
xlim([10 20]); % set the xlims to 10,20
```

Comment: I had tried using it but I am getting the following error ??? Error using ==> scatter at 79
C must be a single color, a vector the same length as X, or an M-by-3 matrix.     probably because z which is derived from a,e,c cannot be limited as x and y can

Comment: @RohanChakrabarty, I'm not sure that error has anything to do with setting limits.  Post a new question and I'll help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is probably too obvious to be the solution to your problem, but in this line:

```
scatter(x(1:end-1), y(1:end-1),5, lg);
```

If `lg` is the same size as `x` and `y`, then clearly this is wrong and you need to do:

```
scatter(x(1:end-1), y(1:end-1),5, lg(1:end-1));
```

If this does not solve your problem, then as I stated in my comment you must provide complete code that we can run to reproduce the problem, including sample data for the `x`, `y`, and `lg` vectors.

Comment: Though this was not d answer, but ur previous answer somehow works now...thanks